# Fetch data using php mysql and angularJS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, cakephp

I using cakephp and angularJS. But I can not fetch data from controller to angularJS. 
My controller:

```
$note2 = $this->Note->find('all', array(
        'fields' => 'id, title, create_at'
    ));
 $data_arr = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($note2 as $not){
        $data_arr[$i]['id'] = $not['Note']['id'];
        $data_arr[$i]['title'] = $not['Note']['title'];
        $data_arr[$i]['create_at'] = $not['Note']['create_at'];
        $i++;
    }
echo json_encode($data_arr);
```

My file js:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);
myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http){
$http.get('/thunder_note/notes/index').then(function(result){
    $scope.list_data=result;
    });
});
```

My view:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
....
<tr ng-repeat="zaa in list_data">
<td>{{zaa.id}}</td>
<td>{{zaa.title}}</td>
<td>{{zaa.create_at}}</td>
....
<div>
```

My json_encode($data_arr)

```
[{"id":"31","title":"bbbbb","create_at":"2017-10-23 13:29:37"},

{"id":"32","title":"cccc","create_at":"2017-10-23 13:29:44"}]
```

But when i console.log(result), follow this image:

[console.log(result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdd5N.png)

I fixed. My solution: in my controller add code: `$this->autoRender=false;`

Comment: Can you fetch the data if you visit `/thunder_note/notes/index` in the browser?

Comment: Note that the data is a property of `result` .... `$scope.list_data=result.data`

Comment: @charlietfl it's not working. Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]  :(

Comment: @kontrollanten i can.

Comment: @charlietfl i edited my problem. please check it. thanks.

Comment: I fixed. I use $this->autoRender = false to disable view and layout. It's working. :)